# How can I find a mean for each variable (in class "character") with multiple columns of numeric data ("rating")?

Tags: r

I have a dataset on movies rating from different countries (columns "movies", "country") and their rating worldwide (column "rating"). How can I find a mean of rating for each country, considering that each country has multiple movies?

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If I got data format right something like this should work.

```
require(data.table)
# create test data set, you can use setDT to create data.table from data.frame
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(movies=rep(c("Movie 1", "Movie 2", "Movie 3"), 3), 
country=rep(c("US", "UK", "IE"), each=3), rating=sample(9))
#   movies country rating
#1 Movie 1      US      3
#2 Movie 2      US      7
#3 Movie 3      US      9
#4 Movie 1      UK      6
#5 Movie 2      UK      5
#6 Movie 3      UK      1
#7 Movie 1      IE      2
#8 Movie 2      IE      8
#9 Movie 3      IE      4

# calculate average rating
dt[, .(rating = mean(rating)), by = country]
```